# How to secure my code in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, typescript, static, angular

Imagine have an app, which has heavy admin interface with so much cool features, and simple user interface, like one button.
I know i can restrict my access to my urls (components), based on something.(key, hash or whatever). 
What i want to achieve, is: 
If backend decide i am a regular user - it sends only small app (with only one component with button for example) and user do not receive all heavy components code for (whole site features). So he will be not able to analyse my admin javascript.
If backend deicdes I'm staff - front-end should receive all necessary components for staff. If I'm admin, I should receive all components.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be related to javascript or angular2. The server you use needs to decide if it sends something or not. Please target this question to tags that are related to the server you're using.

Comment: There is no question about server implementation, its easy include or not some js, based on criteria, but Angular2 compile whole app in one js! In angular1 I can just add my heavy component script or not based on condition. But in angular2 , typescript includes everything, what component imports. And it is one file

Comment: I see. You could build two different applications (while sharing the commong parts). I assume that the lazy loading feature of routes breaks the application into parts (not tried myself) and I guess the build tools need to support this. There is ongoing work. The whole fuss about `router` and `router-deprecated` and again a new router was at least for a big part caused by the requirement for lazy loading.

Comment: Imagine I have 5x5 table describing roles for users (superadmin, staff, guest and user), If so, do i need to have 25 apps? Ideally I want still have one app. Your answer will work, but not for my situation. I really have to have different roles, not so simple as 2 roles.

Comment: <quote> But in angular2 , typescript includes everything, what component imports. And it is one file</quote>. But you could use amd module with requirejs and dont compile everything in one file only

Comment: Your question mentions only 2 users and I think this is a valid suggestions for two users. I see that this is not practical for an exponential combination.

Comment: It will be nice to use amd with require I think. Is it possible with webpack?

Comment: sorry I don't use webpack, try to investigate here: https://webpack.github.io/docs/amd.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The questions is:

### Do you really need it?

The general pattern is to send whole js bundled file (you can obfuscate it, minify etc.) but it still will include templates and code you've implemented. For most cases it's not the problem because there are really no sensitive data. The point is to properly secure REST API endpoints.

### If you really wanted to

You can use e.g. [webpack](https://webpack.github.io) or any other bundling system that will allow you to create separate bundles and will load proper chunk of code only when it's needed (e.g. after successful login). Here you have [webpack async loading](https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto#9-async-loading).This resource will be protected by the hosting server (will require authorized user - just like REST API calls).

Comment: Thank you! Now my vision is complete